# For a teardrop shape, which orientation has the least drag?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

Here's the shape:

[image]

(Well, that's a cross section of the shape. The actual object is a 3D shape obtained by rotating that outline around the y-axis.)

Let's pretend it's a solid, rigid object flying through the air. It can fly **point-first** or **curve-first**. Which way produces the least drag?

Assume it's normal air at room temperature. The angle of attack will be constant. It will be subsonic speeds.

BTW, is there a huge difference in drag? If not then it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Although aerodynamics is a big part of this site it should be something that relates to aviation. A non-aviation related aerodynamics question like this is better in physics.se

Comment: VTC since the 3D shape, as described, does not appear to be about aviation, specifically, and would fit better in physics.se

Comment: Why did someone VTC to meta.aviation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Belongs on Physics.se

Comment: Look at [this familiar object](http://road.cc/sites/default/files/styles/main_width/public/images/Lazer%20Wasp%20Air%20/Lazer%20Wasp%20Air.jpg?itok=kYkV-iLv), this is a practical use and an answer. Beware of [imitations](http://content.bikeroar.com/system/content/000/088/140/original/watermelon_bike_helmet.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

The design looks similar to the wheel fairings found on many Cessna-type aircraft. They lead curve-first.

If it was going tip-first, you could have a nice laminar airflow initially, but once it reaches the curve, the airflow will separate from the surface and produce a big wake with associated drag. By leading with the curve you can have a laminar flow right to the tip, with only a little bit of drag.